# VelocityJS in a TypeScript project throws '../node_modules/@types/velocity-animate/index.d.ts is not a module'

Tags: angular, animation, typescript, velocity.js, typescript-types

I'm trying to import VelocityJS (a JS animation framework) into a TypeScript project using the npm commands below.

First I have installed jQuery and it's @types using:

```
npm install --save jquery

npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

then imported jQuery in the .ts file using:

```
import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';
```

then I've installed velocity-animate using

```
npm install --save velocity-animate

npm install --save-dev @types/velocity-animate
```

but when I try to run the application using '`ng serve`' it throws an error on compile: 
 **'../node_modules/@types/velocity-animate/index.d.ts' is not a module.'**

Did anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Did solve the problem? How?